# Hiding the Keyboard On Multiple Text Fields

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, iboutlet

I tried a few codes, and I am still suck so I appreciate any help towards a Swift noob.

I would like to hide the keyboard on multiple text fields every time the enter key is pressed.

The code I have so far doesn't achieve much of anything so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var priceTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var payoutTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var leasingPeriodTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var priceLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var payoutLabel: UILabel!

var amt: Int = 0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    priceTextField.delegate = self

    priceTextField.delegate = self

    priceTextField.placeholder = updateAmount()
}


func priceTextFieldShouldReturn(_ priceTextField: UITextField) -> Bool {
     self.view.endEditing(true)
     return true
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct method of the `UITextFieldDelegate`

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
   textField.resignFirstResponder()
   return true 
}
```

replace it with the one you named `priceTextFieldShouldReturn`

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the delegate for each textfield.

```
priceTextField.delegate = self 
payoutTextField.delegate = self 
leasingPeriodTextField. delegate = self
```

and implement this method from the `UITextFieldDelegateProtocol`

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
   textField.resignFirstResponder()
   return true 
}
```